# Maximal dissipative operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ is Hilbert.

$A:D(A)\subset H\rightarrow H $an operator

$I:H \rightarrow H$ the identity operator

$\lambda>0$

Is this implication is true?

$A-\lambda I$ is maximal dissipative operator $\implies A$ is maximal dissipative operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick $A = I$ and $\lambda = 2 > 0$. Then $A - \lambda I = -I$ is maximally dissipative. But $A$ is not dissipative.